# Help identify a resistor-like component

Tags: components, identification

I came across this component, it looks like a resistor but has no color bands:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does it measure on an ohmmeter? Is that right hand character on the first line a 'K' or a(n?) 'И'?

Comment: Inductor probably.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it looks like a horizontally flipped 'N'. It measures 0.2 MΩ on a multimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it's a Soviet-era metal film resistor. M20 means 0.2M (200K), and (guessing more) the 83 is the date code (1983).

I'm not sure what the Cyrillic 'И' signifies, maybe tolerance or something else.

Not worth much!